# Creating, writing to and reading files

Tags: java, file

I know there are many questions related to this, but I still do not follow. I have copied the below code from a tutorial on how to create, write to and read from a file. There is a `CreateFile` class, a `ReadFile` class and a `Demo` class:

CreateFile.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CreateFile {
    private Formatter x;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Formatter("chinese.txt");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("You have an error");
        }
    }

    public void addRecords(){
        x .format("%s%s%s", "20 ", "bucky ", "robers");
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
}
```

ReadFile.java

```
public class ReadFile {
    private Scanner x;

    public void openFile()
    {
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }
    }

    public void readFile()
    {
        while(x.hasNext()) 
        {
            String a = x.next();
            String b = x.next();
            String c = x.next();

            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", a,b,c);
        }
    }
    public void closeFile()
    {
        x.close();
    }

}


public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreateFile g = new CreateFile();
        g.openFile();
        g.addRecords();
        g.closeFile();

        WordCounter r = new WordCounter();
        r.openFile();
        r.readFile();
        r.closeFile();
    }
```

In `Demo.java` if I remove the last four statements related to reading the file, the first four statements related to opening and writing to a file run without error. However, once I add

```
WordCounter r = new WordCounter();
r.openFile();
r.readFile();
r.closeFile();
```

and run the program, it outputs: `Exception in thread "main" could not find file.` I am not sure what is going on, is the file `chinese.txt` never being created?

Comment: Read the code carefully: from which file is ReadFile reading?

Comment: [Javadoc Tutorial for File IO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

Comment: @JBNizet I feel like half my questions on  this site wind up being foolish mistakes... thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you look into serialization it much easier and simpler than writing to .txt files.

But if you really need to do .txt files this is how you write to a .txt file

```
    //This gets your project directory
    private String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    //call save()
    String save("test.txt", "This is will be save to a test.txt file");

    private boolean save(String textfile String outputtext){
        String filepath = projectPath + textfile;

        try{
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath));
            writer.write(outputtext);
            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException e) { }

        return true;
    }
```

And this is how you read it

```
    private String load(String textfile){
        String temp="";
        String filepath = projectPath + textfile;
        try{
            BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
            while(true){
                //this will read one line at a time you can append it output
                try {
                    temp+= reader.readLine();
                    //If no more lines break out of the loop
                    if(line==null)
                        break;

                }catch(IOException e){}
            }
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){}
        //Return contents of the file you loaded
        return temp;
    }
```

I hope that this code is clear enough. If you have any further questions let me know. I'll gladly answer them.

Comment: Thus code does not compile, and exhibits a lot of poor practice.

Comment: It doesn't compile because it's only a part of a bigger project. I just copied it from one of my assignments. It should work fine. It does for me.